# Apache server: Git Pull takes too much time

Tags: git, apache, git-pull

I am using an apache server where git pull and push takes too much time sometimes almost 8-10 mins. Eventually it takes pull and do push correctly. 
I tried git gc and git clean command also.
I am not sure what is the root cause of this issue.

Please assist me to post the required information as i am unsure about what all information is required to post.

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, how large is your repo?  Do you have a lot of really large binary files there?

Comment: Check the size of your repo, networking (e.g. routing timeouts, proxies).

Comment: No, there are not more than 2-3 images. and it has around 45-50 files.

Comment: INFO: The repository is used by 4 people using a single account. And the repository is on Bitbucket.